# Why does my code still have the warning: `warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast`?

Tags: java

Why does my code still have the warning: `warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast`? 
When I use '-Xlint', the return is as this :

```
demo1.java:31: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        LinkedList<String> queueB = (LinkedList<String>)(queueA.clone());        
                                                        ^
  required: LinkedList<String>
  found:    Object
1 warning
```

But I do not understand it. I used 'LinkedList'. 
could anyone give a help ?

The below is my code.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class demo1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<String> queueA = new LinkedList<String>();
        queueA.add("element 1");
        queueA.add("element 2");
        queueA.add("element 3");

        Iterator<String> iterator = queueA.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String element = iterator.next();
        }

        for (Object object : queueA)
        {
            String element = (String) object;
            System.out.println("queueA: "+element);
        }


        LinkedList<String> queueB = (LinkedList<String>)(queueA.clone());        
        System.out.println("queueB," +  queueB.remove());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an unchecked cast warning because [`clone` returns an `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#clone--), not a `LinkedList<String>`.  The compiler just sees that `clone` returns an `Object`, so casting to a generic `LinkedList<String>` will cause this warning.  Because `clone` loses any type information, using clone there is no way to avoid this warning without `@SuppressWarnings`.

You can however just create a new `LinkedList` by using [the constructor that takes a `Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList-java.util.Collection-) as its argument.

```
LinkedList<String> queueB = new LinkedList<String>(queueA);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The compiled code will actually look like that :

```
LinkedList<String> queueB = (LinkedList)(queueA.clone());
```

Thus, type safety is no longer guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because there is a chance for a `ClassCastException` to occur. The compiler is not sure if its safe to cast it that way. Since you know beforehand that it has to be a `LinkedList<String>`, you could use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation but I would suggest not to do the unchecked cast.

Comment: From the compiler point of view, there is always a chance of `ClassCastException`. Only the programmer can know (or believe) that a cast will never fail. This is not a correct answer.